# Extracting SSH public key from message with libssh

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, ssh, rsa

I am using [node-libssh](https://github.com/rvagg/node-libssh) as a nice binding to libssh in my node application and can simulate an ssh server quite easily. However I need to extract the public key from an incoming SSH session. I need a stringified version of the key for later usage in a db query and it must match the same format as you would find in id_rsa.pub file.

I have been able to narrow it down to needing a way to convert between a libssh `ssh_key` to a char array.

Its simple enough to use `ssh_key pubKey = ssh_message_auth_pubkey(message);` to get a `ssh_key` version of the pubkey, however there appear to be no methods within libssh to convert from an ssh_key into any other format which can be passed back to my nodejs process. I forsee something like this being the solution:

```
ssh_key authKey = ssh_message_auth_pubkey(m->message);
const char *pubKey = ssh_key_to_char(authKey);
if (pubKey)
  instance->Set(NanSymbol("pubKey"), v8::String::New(pubKey));
```

But naturally it's not that simple as no method `ssh_key_to_char` exists, I would really appreciate any pointers here.

Comment: did you see [this](http://api.libssh.org/stable/group__libssh__string.html#ga65cbd5f2c5f02599c1c285efd1f06351)?

Comment: Yes, however I have been unable to find a way to convert ssh_key to ssh_string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging for quite a while I was able to find this method which I was able to use to build this functionality:

`ssh_pki_export_pubkey_base64(ssh_key, char*)`

This converts an ssh_key into its base64 equivalent.